# Groovy syntax not working with backslashes

Tags: bash, find, bash-scripting, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to use a backslash on the command bellow at groovy syntax:

```
find /path/folder-* -type f -iname "file*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

When I try to build this command on a Jenkins pipeline give me an error about this syntax. Even before I do this command have a warning with red syntax on Jenkins form field saying unexpected char: '\'.

What could I do for replace or fix error with this backslash ?

Groovy commands:

```
node ("instance") {
    stage ("cleaning folders"){
        sh '''        
        find /root/logfiles/instance* -type f -iname "file*" -exec rm -f {} \;
        '''
    }
    stage ("instance1"){
        sh '''
        rm -f /root/logfiles/instance1/*
        echo instance1; 
        scp 100.0.0.50:/var/log/file1.log /root/logfiles/instance1/file1.log;
        scp 100.0.0.50:/var/log/file2.log /root/logfiles/instance1/file2.log;
        '''
    }
    stage ("instance1"){
        sh '''
        rm -f /root/logfiles/instance2/*
        echo instance2; 
        scp 100.0.0.51:/var/log/file1.log /root/logfiles/instance2/file1.log;
        scp 100.0.0.51:/var/log/file2.log /root/logfiles/instance2/file2.log;
        '''
    }
}
```

**Notice:** I have `rm -f` for all instances at this moment. Will substitute all `rm -f` to the `find` command on the stage cleaning folders.

Tks in advance

Comment: this hybrid slash wont help you? ` ∖ `

Comment: Could you please post your Groovy script (or Pipeline, or whatever it is that you're using to run that command)?

Comment: Pasted on question body the groovy script. @jayhendren

Comment: Since the slash character is simply escaping the following one, it may be that you just need to remove ir.

Comment: @davidgo in this particular case the backslash is definitely necessary to ensure the semicolon is parsed by find and not the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help to escape your escape character, as funny as this might sound. Just put another backslash in front of your backslash:

```
stage ("cleaning folders"){
    sh '''        
    find /root/logfiles/instance* -type f -iname "file*" -exec rm -f {} \\;
    '''
}
```

At least IntelliJ does not mark this as syntactically wrong.

Comment: It sound that worked fine. Tks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually in your case I would not even bother to figure out proper escaping:

```
stage ("cleaning folders"){
    sh '''        
    find /root/logfiles/instance* -type f -iname "file*" -exec rm -f {} +
    '''
}
```

When you pass a semicolon to `-exec`, find constructs multiple commands, one for each result of the find operation (e.g. `rm -f /root/logfiles/instance/file1.log`, `rm -f /root/logfiles/instance/file2.log`, ...), but when you use a plus, find constructs a single command with multiple arguments, which is much more efficient and fast (e.g. `rm -f /root/logfiles/instance/file1.log /root/logfiles/instance/file2.log ...`).  See the man page for find for more detail (sorry I can't quote the man page or provide more detail right now; I'm on mobile).

Comment: There is a limit to how long a command line can be. So be careful if you have a lot of files.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use dollar slashy which disables string interpolation and changes escape char to $.

```
stage ("cleaning folders"){
    sh script: $/
    find /root/logfiles/instance* -type f -iname "file*" -exec rm -f {} \;
    /$
}
```

Comment: A small addition: "dollar slashy" strings do indeed support string interpolation [see section 4.8](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings). I'm very new to Groovy and so this is still foreign, but this seems over complicated. However, it is what I needed for Jenkins and the `sh` command in my Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following `$/ yor backscalsh file path /$`. For example:

```
document root = $/home\test\new/$
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this particular task with `find` is to use its `-delete` action, which also avoids the need to even use a backslash in this case: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Using-the-_002ddelete-action